# Apollo Subscription doesn't seem to get called on Mutation

Tags: apollostack, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

New to Apollo, so I decided to take the [most simple example I found](https://github.com/apollostack/frontpage-server) and try to work it in a slightly different way.  My code can be [found here](https://github.com/mbabauer/apollo_node_simple).

The problem I am having is that the Subscription doesn't seem to get called when I call the Mutation `createTask()`.  The Mutation and Subscription are defined in schema.graphql as:

```
type Mutation {
  createTask(
    text: String!
  ): Task
}

type Subscription {
  taskCreated: Task
}
```

And in resolvers.js as:

```
Mutation: {
  createTask(_, { text }) {
    const task = { id: nextTaskId(), text, isComplete: false };
    tasks.push(task);
    pubsub.publish('taskCreated', task);
    return task;
  },
},
Subscription: {
  taskCreated(task) {
    console.log(`Subscript called for new task ID ${task.id}`);
    return task;
  },
},
```

What I am expecting to happen is that I would get a console.log in the server every time I run the following in the client:

```
mutation Mutation($text: String!) {
  createTask(text:$text) {
    id
    text
    isComplete
  }
}
```

But nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: Happen to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: I wish I did.  Haven't had time to investigate it either.

Comment: Having the same issue :c

Answer (score 0):

The subscription resolver function is called when there is actually a subscription to the GraphQL Subscription.

As you did not add a client which uses `subscriptions-transport-ws` and the `SubscriptionClient` for subscribing to your websocket and the subscription it will not work.

What you could do is add the subscription Channel to the `setupFunctions` of the `SubscriptionManager` and therein you get the value that the `pubsub.publish` function delivers.

Could look like this:

```js
...

const WS_PORT = 8080;

const websocketServer = createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});

websocketServer.listen(WS_PORT, () => console.log( // eslint-disable-line no-console
  `Websocket Server is now running on http://localhost:${WS_PORT}`
));

const subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager({
  schema: executableSchema,
  pubsub: pubsub,
  setupFunctions: testRunChanged: (options, args) => {
    return {
      taskCreated: {
        filter: (task) => {
          console.log(task); // sould be log when the pubsub is called
          return true;
        }
      },
    };
  },
  ,
});

subscriptionServer = new SubscriptionServer({
  subscriptionManager: subscriptionManager
}, {
  server: websocketServer,
  path: '/',
});

...
```